# How to restore default Ubuntu startup Splash Screen?

Tags: plymouth

Some time ago I changed the default startup of my Ubuntu 12.04. I did it in this way:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove usplash` and `sudo apt-get usplash=0`

Now, during startup I see white letters on black background. No Ubuntu-logo. Could you please tell me how I can restore default Ubuntu startup-splash? I tried to install usplash with no luck:

`adam @ myubuntu: ~ $ sudo apt-get install usplash`

`[sudo] password for adam:Reading package lists ... readyBuilding dependency treeReading state information ... readyPackage usplash is not available, but is referred to by another package.This usually means that the package is missing, has been replaced by anotheror package is not available at another source.`

Also I set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and used `sudo update-grub`

Help is appreciated!
~Regards

Comment: Offhand, I'm pretty sure the newer release of Ubuntu use Plymouth and not Usplash to show a boot-up splash screen (after GRUB and before LightDM).